# TCP/IP stack in busybox

Tags: c, busybox

Can someone tell me: where can i find `TCP/IP` stack in `Busybox` source code ?

Comment: you can't. Busybox doesn't implement a TCP/IP stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busybox does not contain a TCP/IP stack.  It makes [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to the operating system to do networking operations.

Here is a good starting place to read about the kernel side of things: [Anatomy of the Linux networking stack](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-networking-stack/).

Answer (score 1):

In Unix-based Systems, the TCP/IP stack is actually built into the kernel, not user space, so Busybox doesn't actually implement it. If you want to actually find that stack, look in the Linux kernel that you will use with busybox. Many people choose to use the older (2.4) kernels because they are lighter weight than later ones.